# ng-repeate for multple data object

Tags: angularjs

I am working with the angular js. I got responce like below :

```
"data": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Afghanistan",
  "sortname": "AF",
  "deleted_at": null,
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": "2017-01-28 06:36:56",
  "states": [
    {
      "id": 42,
      "name": "Badakhshan",
      "country_id": 1,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    },
    {
      "id": 43,
      "name": "Badgis",
      "country_id": 1,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Algeria",
  "sortname": "AL",
  "deleted_at": null,
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": "2017-01-28 06:36:56",
  "states": [
   {
     "id": 44,
     "name": "Badakhshan",
     "country_id": 2,
     "deleted_at": null,
     "created_at": null,
     "updated_at": null
   }
  ]
}]
```

So, now I want to display data like country name state name and its action that looks like below :

[image]

Here, i got only country name. State name is not visible.

My angular code is looks like below :

```
<div ng-controller="StatesController as vm">

    <table class="table table-hover dataTable" id="table-editable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Country name</th>
                            <th>State name</th>
                            <th class="text-right">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody dir-paginate="listdata in vm.listdata | itemsPerPage:10" total-items="vm.totalItems">
                        <tr ng-repeat="state in listdata.states">
                            <td>{{listdata.name}}</td>
                            <td >{{state.name}}</td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <a class="edit btn btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="vm.edit(state.id,$index)" data-target="#addNew">
                                    <i class="icon-note"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="vm.remove(state.id,$index)">
                                    <i class="icons-office-52"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
  </div>
```

**Note :** I want to display each state in a different row along with country name.

**Note :** Here I have change HTML code.

It display country and state as I want but it paginate upto 10 countries. Instead of 10 raw. So what should I have to change ?

Comment: How do you want to show states: All in a single line (comma/dash/newline seperated) or each has its own line (multiple country line)?

Comment: @KursadGulseven I want to display each state in a different row along with country.

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
<tr dir-paginate="listdata in vm.listdata.data | itemsPerPage:10"
```

Comment: when I used vm.listdata.data then it does not display anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your `states` property is an array in your object, so you can do:

```
<td>{{ listdata.name }}</td>
<td><span ng-repeat="state in listdata.states">{{ state.name }}</span></td>
```

Or if you only want to display a single state (the first one):

```
<td>{{ listdata.name }}</td>
<td>{{ listdata.states[0].name }}</td>
```

Or if you want a new line for each state:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="listdata in vm.listdata>
    <tr ng-repeat="state in listdata.states">
        <td>{{ listdata.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ state.name }}</dt>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I can not get pagination and edit action when I use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access name from array but as per you json object it should be like below and also similarly you can add headers

```
<td ng-repeat="stateName in listdata.states">{{stateName}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of now is:

```
<td>{{listdata.name}}</td>
<td>
    <span ng-repeat="state in listdata.states">
        {{state.name}}<span ng-if="$index<listdata.states.length">, </span>
    </span>
</td>
```